# iPhone: RF shielding for testing

Tags: iphone

My Enterprise app accesses our server when it first starts up. Because of that, it occasionally crashes in areas where there is no 3G/Edge or wifi connection. I thought I had all the errors trapped, but apparently not. So I need to find a way to simulate a no-signal condition. I've tried wrapping the phone in a plastic bag and aluminum foil, grounded to the wall outlet. I've also tried turning off the wifi and the network function, and putting the phone in airplane mode. That has helped some, but there must be at least one other condition that is causing problems.

Anyone have any idea how I can block all RF signals to the phone?

Comment: why are you testing so roughly..just use reachability classes to check if network connection is available or not...if available then continue the app other wise load an Alert

Answer (score 3):

If you *really* need a no signal condition, you can put your phone in the microwave (don't turn it on!). Microwaves are designed to stop all EMF from getting out, so they'll also stop it from getting in.